# Sealing a roof leak

Tags: leak, water-leak

I have discovered a leak on the roof of my Honda Accord Tourer, most likely either through what appears to be the seam of the roof and side, or where the roof rails mount to the roof.

I need to seal this up, but unsure what method / product would be the best. Any suggestions?

Comment: If this has a sunroof, check to ensure the roof drains are clear.

Comment: Already checked sunroof, drains are clear. When I poured water into the roof rail channel it started dripping into the tailgate motor! That'll explain the blown fuse :D

Comment: Nice. All I have for you beyond the roof drains is to tear the hood liner out and see what's going on. Maybe someone else has dealt with your specific issue before.

Comment: See my answer (to myself), it was more about which method of sealing a seam is the best. I went for weatherproof sealant in the end, looks good so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went down the route of some all weather sealant in the end, covered the entire channel where the two panels meet, along with each mounting point for the roof rails.

Before applying I removed any previous sealant and cleaned with degreaser, seems to have applied well, fingers crossed it keeps the water out when it next rains.

Comment: For those interested: http://www.screwfix.com/p/sika-sikaflex-ebt-all-weather-sealant-black-300ml/79299

Comment: Good fix. Sorry I misunderstood your question in the first place. Don't forget to select your own answer check mark (when it's available).

Comment: No problem @Paulster2, wants me to wait until tomorrow, will come back and house keep then :-)

Comment: Update 15 months on, all weather sealant is still holding well! No leaks at all .